# WPF GridView Column width on different PC resolution

Tags: wpf, gridview, width

How to set width for GridViewColumn that it will work all time on different resolution? For example I have this listView: [image]

And then I open it in another PC (with different resolution) I get this view :

[image]

It is missing few column.
I copy one of my column xaml code :

```
<ListView x:Name="sample" Margin="30,98.4,362,150"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
               AlternationCount="2" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn>

                        <!-- 1st Column-->
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Product" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Grid Height="42px">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding odd}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                                  Width="600" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <TextBlock  Foreground="#B30C0C" Height="42px" Padding="10,5,0,0" Text="{Binding discounText}" 
                                                Visibility="{Binding IsDiscount, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn >
```

How you see I write width parameter in TextBlock. How I have to rewrite it or maybe make some changes in code?

Answer (score 0):

Use relative sizing (with `*`) instead of fixed values. For that, you'll have to move your `Width` setting from the `TextBlock` to the Column itself:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="600*">

    <!-- 1st Column-->
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Product" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid Height="42px">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding odd}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                               TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock  Foreground="#B30C0C" Height="42px" Padding="10,5,0,0" Text="{Binding discounText}" 
                            Visibility="{Binding IsDiscount, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I've set `600*` because the fastest way to keep the current proportions is keeping the same values you have right now, but adding the `*`. But that number can be a lot lower, since it just defines the proportion between columns... Feel free to toy with the values to get the effect you want.

Comment: If I do what you said, I get this error: "600*" string cannot be converted to Lenght.

Comment: What the...? Seems like `GridViewColumn` doesn't accept `*` values :S I guess this is why I always use `DataGrid` instead.